# PHP searching for a string in multiple files within a directory

Tags: php

Im only a begginer in PHP so Im really sorry if it is just a stupid question.I have a directory full of .txt files and I have written a code to find a specific string inside those files and echo the whole line :

```
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\dbl';
$files = scandir($dir,1);
foreach ($files as $lines){
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
    if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
    echo $line;
    }
}
?>
```

However,I keep getting this error : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\search.php on line 19

Comment: If you need speed on many large files then have a look at running [grep](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/grep/grep_13.html) from PHP using [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Answer (score 2):

This error caused by fact that you actually didn't open file within 1-st loop. You must open each file before looping throw lines. 
You can do it with two ways:

1) Using `file_get_contents()` function

2) Using some functions for work with files (fopen(), fclose(), etc)

Go [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$search = 'test';
$dir = 'C:\xampp5.6\htdocs';
$files = scandir($dir,1);
foreach ($files as $lines){
    if(strlen($lines) > 3 && strpos($lines, '.txt') !== false){
        $readfile = fopen('C:\xampp5.6\htdocs/'.$lines, 'r');

        while(!feof($readfile)) {
            $contents = fgets($readfile);
            if(strpos($contents, $search) !== false)
                echo $lines.'<br>';
        }
        fclose($readfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly,thanks! But how can I make it case insensitive? strtolower is very slow because my files are large.

Comment: you can user stripos($contents, $search) too.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***fopen()*** to read each file and then search for the string